# What would be a good use for a memristor?

Tags: memristor

I am an electronics hobbyist and I found something that I hadn't heard of before, named *Memristor*. I found [some information about how memristors work](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/what-are-the-characteristics-of-a-memristor) on this site and I want to know that how it can be used. In which type of application are these components used?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick  but what are the application.How one can use this device?

Comment: What are the characteristics and what are the applications are two separate questions

Comment: @Kortuk, Would've agreed about this being too broad, but if [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/inductors-what-are-they-used-for) is acceptable then I don't see why shouldn't this one be.

Comment: @echad Just because someone speeds without being ticketed does not mean that you can speed without risk of enforcement of the speed limit. If that makes sense, the other was open and no one had flagged it or taken specific note. Another question being open can be a good example for meta discussions but is generally never good evidence that one question should be reopened in a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Memristors have a memory like characteristics, non-voltaile memory. So even when they're powered off they can hold on to the value. This sort of technology can replace how we design memory for computers such as RAM, SSD and Flash.

Resistive Random Access Memory (RRAM):
[image: RRAM]

[source](http://www.eng.utoledo.edu/eecs/faculty_web/~rjha/research_projectsNew.html)

Many applications can take advantage of it such as neural networks, robotics to mimic biological entities in a new way. DARPA is [attempting](http://spectrum.ieee.org/robotics/artificial-intelligence/moneta-a-mind-made-from-memristors) to build a brain using Memristor chips, designed by HP Labs, for neuromorphic computing.
[image: Memristor Synapses]

[source](http://nanowire4.eecs.umich.edu/nano/?p=123)

They can also replace transistor-based crossbar latches since they take up less space.
Logic design is a big area these components can contribute. From crossbar latches to memory, gates and [more](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/skva/Memristor%20Projects/Memristor-%20final%20report_Guy_Nimrod_Winter2012.pdf)

There already exist memristor-based control system patents out there (here's [one example](http://www.google.com/patents/US7609086))

Comment: As you have mention in your very first line how they differ from the RAM or other non volatile memory??

Comment: @user27390 they ["use resistance instead of voltage or charge as the physical state variable"](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v464/n7290/full/nature08940.html%3Fid%3D3731) and take up less space

Comment: If each memresistor has a diode in series, wouldn't that mean it would get set into the state associated with current flow in the diode direction and then permanently stuck there?

Comment: @supercat That doesn't affect the memory writing scheme, it just introduces different energy requirement for setting and resetting of memristor states. Source: **Design exploration of hybrid cmos and memristor circuit by new modified nodal analysis** by W Fei, H Yu, W Zhang, KS Yeo.